# gLTF export just freeze (Blender 2.8)

Tags: gltf

I try to export my model with any preferences, but it's freeze, then blender not responding. I had that one message in console window[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample Blend file?  Also how many textures are used by materials in that model?  Depending on configuration, the glTF exporter does a lot of processing of texture images on export, that other exporters typically don't do, to get them into glTF's PBR arrangement.

Comment: Blender often claims to be "not responding" when processing very large export operations (large scenes, multimillion face geometry, lots of 4k textures, etc...). I find that it often pays off to give it a couple of minutes before terminating, and it usually becomes responsive again.